# how to show category post and title separate loop

Tags: wordpress, tabs

i am making one slider tab, i know have tons of plugins for that but i don't want to use plugins. so i want to show my category post title and post like bellow html formate but i can't. i tried my but my way only content loop not title. if can able to make html like bellow then tabs will work. guys how can i do that.

```
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#content_1" rel="tab_1" class="tab active_tab">Tabs 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content_2" rel="tab_2" class="tab">Tabs 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content_3" rel="tab_3" class="tab">Tabs 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content_4" rel="tab_4" class="tab">Tabs 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#content_5" rel="tab_5" class="tab">Tabs 5</a></li>
    </ul>

so here under li (tabs) put post title 




<div id="content_1" class="tab_view first_tab">
                    <h2>Tab #1</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis netus ut posuere feugiat arcu, purus wisi quis fringilla at, nunc ut eget elit duis erat praesent, ut fermentum lacus turpis cras. Justo gravida erat quam mauris purus, aliquam quisque, eget nisl. Pellentesque nibh duis odio morbi quam, scelerisque convallis aenean quam tincidunt ornare nam nec feugiat sodales tristique.</p>                         
                </div>

<div id="content_1" class="tab_view first_tab">
                    <h2>Horizontal Tab #1</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis netus ut posuere feugiat arcu, purus wisi quis fringilla at, nunc ut eget elit duis erat praesent, ut fermentum lacus turpis cras. Justo gravida erat quam mauris purus, aliquam quisque, eget nisl. Pellentesque nibh duis odio morbi quam, scelerisque convallis aenean quam tincidunt ornare nam nec feugiat sodales tristique.</p>                         
                </div>
<div id="content_1" class="tab_view first_tab">
                    <h2>Horizontal Tab #1</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis netus ut posuere feugiat arcu, purus wisi quis fringilla at, nunc ut eget elit duis erat praesent, ut fermentum lacus turpis cras. Justo gravida erat quam mauris purus, aliquam quisque, eget nisl. Pellentesque nibh duis odio morbi quam, scelerisque convallis aenean quam tincidunt ornare nam nec feugiat sodales tristique.</p>                         
                </div>
<div id="content_1" class="tab_view first_tab">
                    <h2>Horizontal Tab #1</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis netus ut posuere feugiat arcu, purus wisi quis fringilla at, nunc ut eget elit duis erat praesent, ut fermentum lacus turpis cras. Justo gravida erat quam mauris purus, aliquam quisque, eget nisl. Pellentesque nibh duis odio morbi quam, scelerisque convallis aenean quam tincidunt ornare nam nec feugiat sodales tristique.</p>                         
                </div><div id="content_1" class="tab_view first_tab">
                    <h2>Horizontal Tab #1</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis netus ut posuere feugiat arcu, purus wisi quis fringilla at, nunc ut eget elit duis erat praesent, ut fermentum lacus turpis cras. Justo gravida erat quam mauris purus, aliquam quisque, eget nisl. Pellentesque nibh duis odio morbi quam, scelerisque convallis aenean quam tincidunt ornare nam nec feugiat sodales tristique.</p>                         
                </div>
```

see closely `href="#content_1" rel="tab_1"` this #content_  (1,2,3,4,5)should auto. similar  `<div id="content_1"` this content_ also number will auto i mean post number

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
     $args = array(
'post_type' => array('post'), 
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'category_name'=>'my category name' ,
'showposts' => 5 );
$array= get_posts($args); ?>
<ul class="tabs">
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) { ?>    
<li><a href="#content_<?php echo $i+1; ?>" rel="tab_<?php echo $i+1; ?>" class="tab">Tabs 

<?php echo $i+1; ?></a></li>

<?php
$divs.='<div id="content_'.($i+1).'" class="tab_view first_tab">
<h2>'.$array[$i]->post_title.'</h2>
<p>'.$array[$i]->post_content.'</p>                         
                </div>';    
 } ?>
 </ul>

<?php $divs; ?>
```